# named scope with where and where.not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

```
scope :active_without_owner, -> { where(active: true, role: 'owner') }
```

returns active users with role set to 'owner'.

I cannot figure out the syntax to return active users with role other than 'owner'.

I have tried

```
scope :active_without_owner, -> { where(active: true, not(role: 'owner')) }
```

and many many other combinations...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work:

```
scope :active_without_owner, -> { where(active: true).where.not(role: 'owner')) }
```

I'd change it up a bit though and do this so you can reuse `active`:

```
scope :active, -> { where(active: true) }
scope :active_with_owner, -> { active.where(role: 'owner') }
scope :active_without_owner, -> { active.where.not(role: 'owner')) }
```